# Is there any option to operate with 2 lists in one list in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible in Google spreadsheets to have one list which is somehow divided into 2 parts and both of those parts consist of different lists? Something like iframes in HTML.

Comment: And you are not looking for the _[freeze rows](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/54813)_ feature, correct?

Comment: Yes, freeze is not an option :(

Comment: Do you need edit access to both lists?

Comment: Yes, the same as open the same sheet at 2 windows. Something like iframe.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to open the same spreadsheet in two windows and put them side-to-side.